# How to delete a specific commit?

Tags: git, version-control

We have a master branch, a staging branch off of master, and my feature branch off of staging. Here's a diagram:

```
     my_feature: o--o--o---o--o  <= after rebase, contains commits
                /         /         from other_feature
other_feature: o--o      /
              /    \    /
    staging: o--o---o--o 
            /            
   master: o--o--o--o-o--o--o--o--o  <= master
```

I rebased `my_feature` branch after `other_feature` was merged with `staging` with the intention of merging into `staging` but then realized that `my_feature` should be merged directly to `master`.

The problem now is that I have commits from `other_feature` which have no business in `master` at this time.

When I try `git revert --no-commit 65b2e1b`, it returns a list of unmerged files and `fatal: Your index file is unmerged`. I have no idea what this means.

`git status` returns the aforementioned unmerged files. So I ran `git commit -am "revert"` which returns a message `You are currently reverting commit 5a53cd0. nothing to commit, working directory clean`. If I then try `git push` it just says `everything is up to date`

Any suggestions?

Comment: These "unmerged" messages mean that you are in the middle of a merge.  The status you see suggests that you already started this revert, and are still in the middle of it. If you wish to revert the commit, you must finish the merge process manually and `git commit` the reversion. Until then `git push` is not going to be very helpful as Git only pushes *commits*, and an in-progress revert-that-has-a-merge-conflict is not a new commit yet.

Comment: Based on your question update, it sounds like you should not revert at all, but rather undo your original rebase entirely, and re-start the rebasing process with the desired target. If that's correct, instead of finishing your current revert, just `git revert --abort` to terminate it, to get back to your rebased state; then undo your rebase, using the reflog for your feature branch.

Comment: Thanks for help! What if the rebase a few days ago and there's been a ton of work since then?

Now can someone help me understand why people would downvote a question like this? Is it so unreasonable?

Comment: @JesseNovotny, IMO your question makes perfect sense, is adequately represented, and I have no idea whatsoever why anyone would downvote it.

Comment: @JesseNovotny: if you have additional work post-rebase, "undoing" the rebase is a lot more work. You could instead re-rebase (see AnoE's answer), which may or may not be very hard, depending on how many commits there are and whether an interactive rebase (which would let you omit specific commits you brought in via the first rebase) is a good idea. It is hard to say for sure what's *best*, without a lot more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can undo the original rebase with a new rebase:

```
git checkout my_feature
git rebase --onto original_master staging
```

... where `original_master` is the most leftward/downward commit in your ASCII picture, i.e., the commit you originally branched `my_feature` off of (I assume that's what you did, although your picture shows something else with rigorous interpretation of the left-side `o`'s).

This will start off with `original_master`, and then apply every patch from `staging` up to `my_feature`, or, in other words, it will "remove" anything between `original_master` and `staging` from `my_feature`. Figuratively speaking of course, I'm pretty sure you are aware that `git rebase` does not *change* anything and just adds new commits elsewhere...

If that makes sense, great - if not, feel free to ask in a comment so I can clarify.